# Multi Rows Deletion from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can Delete 1.5 Millions Rows From SQL Server 2000, And how much time it will take to complete this task.

I dont want to delete all records from table.... I just want to delete all records which are fullfilling WHERE condition.

EDITED from a comment to an answer below.

"I fire the same query i.e. delete from table_name with Where Clause... Is it possible to Disable Indexing at the running Query, becuase Query is going on from past 20 hr.. Also help me out how i can disable Indexing.."

Comment: Thats I know... but wanna know how much time it will take to delete or complete query..
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to delete all records or not?

Comment: I dont want to delete all records from table.... 
I just want to delete all records which are fullfilling WHERE condition...

Comment: How much time is dependent on how many related tables must be checked, if you are doing cascade delete, if there are triggers on your table, and other factors such as the performance specs of your server and the number of other users accessing the table. It can't be answered in a forum like this.

Answer (score 5):

If (and only if) you want to delete all of the records in a table, you can use DROP TABLE or TRUNCATE TABLE.

DELETE removes one record at a time and records an entry in the transaction log for each deleted row.
TRUNCATE TABLE is much faster because it doesn't record the activity in the transaction log. It removes all rows from a table, but the table structure & its columns, constraints, indexes and so on remain. DROP TABLE would remove those.

Use caution if you decide to TRUNCATE. It's irreversible (unless you have a backup).

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: It answered the question as originally posed. And it provides information for other interested readers who have a similar, but not identical situation. One never knows when one provides an answer whether the original question is going to be changed, does one?

Answer (score 3):

create a second table, inserting all rows from the first that you don't want deleting.

delete the first table

rename the second table to be the first

(or a variation on the above)

This can often be quicker than doing a delete of selected records from a big table.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try deleting in batches too.  I just tested this on a table I have and the delete operation went from 13 seconds to 3 seconds.

```
While Exists(Select * From YourTable Where YourCondition = True)
  Delete Top (100000)
  From   YourTable
  Where  YourCondition = True
```

I don't think you can use the TOP predicate if you are running SQL2000, but it works with SQL2005 and up.  If you are using SQL2000, then you can use this syntax instead:

```
Set RowCount 100000
While Exists(Select * From YourTable Where YourCondition = True)
   Delete 
   From YourTable
   Where  YourCondition = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, But it would be fine if you will suggest what I have to do when query is running from past 20 hr ago...

Should I cancle the query

Comment: It may take 20 hours to cancel the query because it might roll back your transaction.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I think SQL will continue the rollback after the server is restarted.  There's a lot of intelligence built in to SQL Server to make sure your data integrity is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE a=b;
```

When deleting that many rows you may want to disable the indexes so they don't get updated on every delete. Rewriting the indexes on every deletion will significantly slow down the whole process.

You'll want to disable these indexes before beginning your deletion or else there may be table locks already in place.

```
--Disable Index
ALTER INDEX [IX_MyIndex] ON MyTable.MyColumn DISABLE

--Enable Index
ALTER INDEX [IX_MyIndex] ON MyTable.MyColumn REBUILD
```

If you wish to remove all entries in a table you can use TRUNCATE.

Comment: I fire the same query i.e. delete from table_name with Where Clause...
Is it possible to Disable Indexing at the running Query, becuase Query is going on from past 20 hr..

Also help me out how i can disable Indexing....

Comment: can i disable inxing in the running stage of the query

Comment: You might want to cancel your query.

Answer (score 1):

Does the table you are deleting from have multiple foreign keys, or cascaded deletes or triggers?  All of these will impact performance.

Depending on what you want to do and the transactional integrity, can you delete things in small batches e.g. if you are trying to delete 1.5 million records that is 1 years worth of data, can you do it 1 week at a time?

Answer (score 0):

**Delete from** *table* **where** *condition for those 1.5 million rows*

The time depends.

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle it is also possible to use

```
truncate table <table>
```

Not sure if that is standard SQL or available in SQL Server. It will however **clear the whole table** - but then it is quicker than "delete from " (it will also conduct a commit).

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATE will also ignore any referential integrity or triggers on the table.  DELETE FROM ... WHERE will respect both.  The time will depend on the indexing of your condition columns, your hardware, and any additional system load.

Answer (score 0):

The delete SQL is exactly the same as a normal SQL delete

delete from table where [your condition ]

However if your worried about time then I'll assume your question is a little deeper than this. If your table is has a significant number of non-clustered indexes then in some circumstances it may be faster to drop all these indexes first and rebuild after the delete. This *is* unusual but in cases where your straightforward delete is vulnerable to timeout issues it may be helpful

Comment: I fired Query with Delete from table name and with Where condition before 20 hr ago.. Query is still going on...
how much time it will take to compelte.....
is there is chances to disable indexing in the running query

Comment: It is probably because of the logs... you can change logging to SIMPLE and then do the delete, and change logging back, after the delete completes. This will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as select <data you want to keep> from old_table;

index new_table
grant on new table
add constraints on new_table
etc on new_table

drop table old_table
rename new_table to old_table;
```